# How do I archive up the list of people who "like" each of my status updates on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Facebook's "Download Your Information" still doesn't have that feature yet.

Also, most of the normal scripts that allow me to automate the "click more" process also can't really deal with "likes" when more than a few people "like" one of my status updates.

A lot of these "likes" actually do mean a lot to me, and I'd hate to lose them if, say, one of my friends deactivates or deletes their account.

Comment: I don't think Facebook have that feature. A custom Userscript might make this possible.

Comment: Yeah - it's precisely that sort of custom userscript that I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently archivable, the archive only includes

- Photos or videos you've shared on Facebook
- Your Wall posts, messages and chat conversations
- Your friends' names and some of their email addresses

For more info https://www.facebook.com/125713384123802/posts/416616365033501